# Why does uptime report load averages over 1.35 even when the system is idle and not running any apps almost 24 hours after boot?

Tags: mac-mini, performance

I have a Mac Mini (2014 model, 4GB RAM, 500GB storage) I use mostly for testing cross-platform software I'm working on.  It's never been particularly fast but immediately after the latest upgrade from Big Sur to Mac OSX 12.0.1 Monterey, the Mini now runs painfully slowly.

Dropping to a Terminal, a simple `ps aux` and `top` (as root) shows nothing obvious using up the CPU or RAM.  There are only 2 processes with over 1 minute of CPU in the list:

```
2:26.00 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Resources/WindowServer -daemon
4:11.51 /System/Library/DriverExtensions/com.apple.AppleUserHIDDrivers.dext/com.apple.AppleUserHIDDrivers ...
```

But `uptime` consistently reports load averages over 1.35 even though there are no actively running applications other than the desktop:

```
# uptime
 7:46 up 23 hrs, 5 users, load average: 1.35 1.69 1.59
```

Not sure what is going on here.  The only time I've ever seen this kind of behavior is when the host OS handling multiple VMs goes haywire.  But this is flat hardware + OS with the only change being an upgrade to the OS.

Comment: 12.0.1 was as buggy as all heck. 12.2.1 is the latest. Update & test again.

Comment: Unfortunately, even after updating, there is no change.

Comment: I can't say I really understand load averages, but I found this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805802/mac-os-x-load-average Mine is currently showing `load averages: 1.67 1.29 1.21` but it's not very busy [or slow]. I perhaps get the feeling you're noticing the drag on an HD when the system now really wants an SSD. My folks have a fusion drive iMac which always feels like molasses compared to anything with an SSD in it.

Comment: For load averages on *NIX style OSes, anything over 1.0 means the system is experiencing heavy load and going to struggle to keep up.  Anything over 0.8 is usually pretty noticeable.  2 to 10 is barely usable (usually barely enough overhead to stop whatever is causing the problem) while 10+ is hard reboot territory.  CPU is usually the culprit.  Didn't think disk I/O could be the cause but I'll look into that.

Comment: Ah, interesting. After another few days with no reboot [normally, reboots are every two or three months, I'd just been fiddling with some things recently] loads have settled to 0.9. The machine has absolutely no symptoms of being busy or slow in the slightest. I'm not doing anything CPU intensive right now - my DAW isn't running, so about 2.5% total CPU use, 32GB of 64 in use 0 swap. We obviously have very different Macs. Mine is older than yours, a cheesegrater Mac Pro… but mine was one of the fastest ever built [when new & for the next 8 years] & unfortunately yours is one of the slowest.